# Tratamento de string, transformar uma palavra em palíndroma

Tags: c, c++

Como faço para que uma palavra não palíndroma se torne palíndroma, ou seja, quantos caracteres faltam para ela se tornar um palindromo,

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    char *inverte(char *s) // strrev para MACOS/LINUX
    {
        char ch = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int i = strlen(s) - 1;
    
        while (i > j)
        {
            ch = s[i];
            s[i] = s[j];
            s[j] = ch;
            i--;
            j++;
        }
    
        return s;
    }
    
    int removec2(char s[], char car[])
    {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0, j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
            if (s[i] != car[i])
                s[j++] = s[i];
        s[j] = '\0';
        return j;
    }
    
    int main() 
    insira o código aqui{
        char palavra[100], inversa[100], restante[100];
        int valor = 0, i, x;
    
        printf("Digite uma palavra: ");
        gets(palavra);
        strcpy(inversa, palavra);
        inverte(inversa);
        valor = strcmp(palavra, inversa);
    
        if (valor == 0)
        {
            printf("%s %s sao palindromos!\n", palavra, inversa);
            printf("%d\n", valor);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%i\n", removec2(palavra, palavra));
            printf("%s %s nao sao palindromos!\n", palavra, inversa);
            printf("%d\n", valor);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Seu programa tem muitos erros ainda. Respondendo à sua pergunta, podem faltar no máximo `N` caracteres, onde `N` é o tamanho da string - 1. O mínimo claro é `0` se a string já for palíndroma. Em um loop você identifica isso. inserindo as letras na ordem inversa e vendo se a string é palíndroma. Claro que ao final de (n-1) ciclos ela vai ser, já que repetiu todas as letras. Claro que pode precisar de 1 ou duas só...

Answer (score 0):

> Como faço para que uma palavra não palíndroma se torne palíndroma, ou seja, quantos caracteres faltam para ela se tornar um palindromo?

Considere que para uma palavra de `N` letras pode precisar de no máximo `N-1` letras para ter um palíndromo.

#### Exemplos

**Stack** não é palíndromo e tem **5** letras. E precisa inserir o máximo, **4** letras, para ter um palíndromo: **StackcatS**

**ABCDCB** não é palíndromo e tem **6** letras. E precisa inserir apenas **1** letra, para ter um palíndromo: **ABCDCBA**

#### Isso em C

Antes de qualquer coisa precisa de algo que diga se uma palavra é palíndroma, mas sem escrever nada na tela, apenas o simples: retorna 0 se a palavra não é palindroma.

Considere

```
    int  eh_pal(const char*);
```

por exemplo.

Eis uma possível implementação

```
// o simples: retorna 1 se palindroma ou 0
int eh_pal(const char* palavra)
{
    if (palavra == NULL) return 0;
    if (*palavra == 0) return 0;
    if (*(palavra + 1) == 0) return 1;
    size_t      tam = strlen(palavra);
    const char* pE  = palavra;
    const char* pD  = palavra + tam - 1;
    for (size_t lim = 0; lim < tam; lim += 1)
        if (*pE++ != *pD--) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

#### Determinando quantas letras faltam

Uma maneira ingênua de fazer é o que se faria no papel: já se sabe que no máximo será preciso inserir `N-1` letras. Então deve bastar num loop inserir a partir de uma letra e chamar a função acima e ver se chegou a um palíndromo.
Uma pegadinha: é preciso inserir as letras ao contrário nas sub-strings, afinal essa é a definição de palíndromo

#### Eis uma possível implementação

```
// retorna o numero de digitos que falta para
// 'palavra' ser palindromo ou -1 em caso de erro
int quantos_faltam(const char* pal)
{
    if (pal == NULL) return -1;
    if (*pal == 0) return -1;
    if (eh_pal(pal)) return 0; // ok ja eh palindromo
    size_t lim  = strlen(pal) - 1; // o maximo que pode acrescentar
    size_t maximo = lim + lim + 3;
    char*  nova = (char*)malloc(maximo);
    memset(nova, 0, maximo);
    strcpy(nova, pal);
    char*       sufixo = nova + lim;
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= lim; i += 1)
    {  // acrescenta i letras
        for (size_t j = 1; j <= i; j += 1)
            *(sufixo + j) = *(pal + i - j);
        if (eh_pal(nova))
        {   free(nova);
            return i;
        }
    };  // for
    free(nova);
    return -1; // so para contentar o compilador
}
```

E a lógica é essa mesma do papel e caneta: ir completando a string e chamando a função `eh_pal()` para ver se já deu certo. É claro que com `N-1` letras sempre vai gerar um palíndromo.

### Um teste completo para as duas funções

O exemplo a seguir testa essas funções e implementa uma função que retorna exatamente o pedido. A partir daí a função de teste monta o palíndromo que seria gerado e mostra na tela, como uma cortesia para facilitar o teste, mas sem mexer no código da função-alvo.

#### saída

```
6 testes para eh_pal():

01/06: "ABCBA"  tamanho=5: palindromo: Sim
02/06: "ABBA"   tamanho=4: palindromo: Sim
03/06: "A"      tamanho=1: palindromo: Sim
04/06: ""       tamanho=0: palindromo: Nao
05/06: "outra coisa"    tamanho=11: palindromo: Nao
06/06: "ABCDEXCBA"      tamanho=9: palindromo: Nao


11 testes para quantos_faltam():

01/11: "ABBA"   tamanho=4: ja e' palindromo
02/11: "ABCDCB" tamanho=6: Faltam 1 letras para um palindromo: [A]
03/11: "AB"     tamanho=2: Faltam 1 letras para um palindromo: [A]
04/11: ""       tamanho=0:Palavra invalida
05/11: "outra coisa"    tamanho=11: Faltam 10 letras para um palindromo: [sioc artuo]
06/11: "ABCDCBA"        tamanho=7: ja e' palindromo
07/11: "ABCDCB" tamanho=6: Faltam 1 letras para um palindromo: [A]
08/11: "ABCDC"  tamanho=5: Faltam 2 letras para um palindromo: [BA]
09/11: "ABCD"   tamanho=4: Faltam 3 letras para um palindromo: [CBA]
10/11: "Stack"  tamanho=5: Faltam 4 letras para um palindromo: [catS]
11/11: "Overflow"       tamanho=8: Faltam 7 letras para um palindromo: [olfrevO]
```

#### o código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int  eh_pal(const char*);
int  quantos_faltam(const char*);

void testa_eh_pal();
void testa_quantos();

int main()
{
    testa_eh_pal();
    testa_quantos();
    return 0;
}

// o simples: retorna 1 se palindroma ou 0
int eh_pal(const char* palavra)
{
    if (palavra == NULL) return 0;
    if (*palavra == 0) return 0;
    if (*(palavra + 1) == 0) return 1;
    size_t      tam = strlen(palavra);
    const char* pE  = palavra;
    const char* pD  = palavra + tam - 1;
    for (size_t lim = 0; lim < tam; lim += 1)
        if (*pE++ != *pD--) return 0;
    return 1;
}

// retorna o numero de digitos que falta para
// 'palavra' ser palindromo ou -1 em caso de erro
int quantos_faltam(const char* pal)
{
    if (pal == NULL) return -1;
    if (*pal == 0) return -1;
    if (eh_pal(pal)) return 0; // ok ja eh palindromo
    size_t lim  = strlen(pal) - 1; // o maximo que pode acrescentar
    size_t maximo = lim + lim + 3;
    char*  nova = (char*)malloc(maximo);
    memset(nova, 0, maximo);
    strcpy(nova, pal);
    char*       sufixo = nova + lim;
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= lim; i += 1)
    {  // acrescenta i letras
        for (size_t j = 1; j <= i; j += 1)
            *(sufixo + j) = *(pal + i - j);
        if (eh_pal(nova))
        {   free(nova);
            return i;
        }
    };  // for
    free(nova);
    return -1; // so para contentar o compilador
}

// testa a funcao com umas strings simples
void testa_eh_pal()
{
    const char* res[]   = {"Nao", "Sim"};
    static const char* teste[] = {
        "ABCBA", "ABBA", "A", "", "outra coisa", "ABCDEXCBA"};
    const int N = sizeof(teste) / sizeof(teste[0]);

    printf("%d testes para eh_pal():\n\n", N);
    for (int t = 0; t < N; t += 1)
    {
        printf(
            "%02d/%02d: \"%s\"\ttamanho=%d: palindromo: "
            "%s\n",
            1 + t, N, teste[t], strlen(teste[t]),
            res[eh_pal(teste[t])]);
    }
    return;
}

void testa_quantos()
{
    const char* palavra[] = {
        "ABBA",
        "ABCDCB",
        "AB",
        "",
        "outra coisa",
        "ABCDCBA",
        "ABCDCB",
        "ABCDC",
        "ABCD",
        "Stack",
        "Overflow"
    };
    const int N = sizeof(palavra) / sizeof(palavra[0]);
    printf("\n\n%d testes para quantos_faltam():\n\n", N);
    for (int res, t = 0; t < N; t += 1)
    {
        res = quantos_faltam(palavra[t]);
        switch (res)
        {
            case -1:
                printf(
                    "%02d/%02d: \"%s\"\ttamanho=%d:"
                    "Palavra invalida\n",
                    1 + t, N, palavra[t],
                    strlen(palavra[t]));
                break;
            case 0:
                printf(
                    "%02d/%02d: \"%s\"\ttamanho=%d: "
                    "ja e' palindromo\n",
                    1 + t, N, palavra[t],
                    strlen(palavra[t]));
                break;
            default:
                printf(
                    "%02d/%02d: \"%s\"\ttamanho=%d: Faltam "
                    "%d letras para um palindromo: [",
                    1 + t, N, palavra[t],
                    strlen(palavra[t]), res);
                for (int i = 1; i <= res; i += 1)
                {
                    printf("%c", palavra[t][res - i]);
                };
                printf("]\n");
                break;
        };  // switch()
    };      // for
    return;
}
```

Aos vigilantes de plantão: eu *sempre* uso um cast no retorno de `malloc()`, mesmo tempo lido o C-faq do final dos anos 90. Não é preciso me lembrar disso.

Não testei extensivamente mas acho que dá pra ter uma idéia de uma maneira de escrever isso.

Answer (score -2):

Olá, seu objetivo é checar se é palíndromo, senão é completar, correto?
Eu estive pesquisando e [aqui](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-check-given-string-palindrome/) tem o exemplo de checar se é palíndroma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
// A function to check if a string str is palindrome
void isPalindrome(char str[])
{
    // Start from leftmost and rightmost corners of str
    int l = 0;
    int h = strlen(str) - 1;
 
    // Keep comparing characters while they are same
    while (h > l)
    {
        if (str[l++] != str[h--])
        {
            printf("%s is not a palindrome\n", str);
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("%s is a palindrome\n", str);
}
 
// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    isPalindrome("abba");
    isPalindrome("abbccbba");
    isPalindrome("geeks");
    return 0;
}
```

Agora vejamos, supondo que eu insiro `isso`, inverte para `ossi`, o esperado é `***isso -> ossi***` então desenvolvi este código abaixo:

```
//Requer stdlib.h para memset, malloc e free.

void fillNonPalindrome(char* str, char* buffer){
    
    char* tmp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) + 1);
    char palindrome[(strlen(str) * 2) - 1], appen[strlen(str) - 1];
    int start = -1, end = strlen(str);
  
    memset(appen, 0, sizeof(appen));
    memset(palindrome, 0, sizeof(palindrome));
  
    while(end + 2 > start - 2){
        palindrome[start++] = str[end--];
    }
    palindrome[start] = str[end];
    start = 1;
    while(start < strlen(str)){
        *tmp = str[start++];
        strcat(appen, tmp);
    }
    
    strcat(palindrome, appen);
    strcpy(buffer, palindrome);
    memset(appen, 0, sizeof(appen));
    memset(palindrome, 0, sizeof(palindrome));
    free(tmp);
}

int main()
{
    char* text = "abcdef";
    char buf[11] = {0}; //6 + 5
    fillNonPalindrome(text, buf);
    printf("%s", buf); //fedcbabcdef
    return 0;
}
```

Nessa função a saída é por `buffer`, precisa declarar uma variável com a alocação necessária para a saída logo: `"isso" -> 4 + 3 <- "sso"`.

Se por acaso que saber o que falta para ser palíndromo, pule o primeiro caractere. Olhe o segundo loop `while` que entederá.

Comment: A julgar pelo título a função deveria retornar _quantos caracteres é preciso inserir para que a palavra se torne palíndroma_. Um número.